# How to change the first word of a string into uppercase using only String class

Tags: java, string

I am working on a Java Lab and have completed about 5 of 7 tasks of manipulating a string entered by the end-user. One task however is to change the first word only of the string to all upper case. We are only allowed to use methods of the String class (StringBuffer & StringBuilder not allowed), which makes this a bit more manual.

Converting an entire string to uppercase is easy enough:

```
String upper = userInput.toUpperCase();
```

But only part of the string is tricking me.

I'm thinking of doing a while loop where each string index gets converted into uppercase until the loop reaches a ' '. So something like this:

```
String stringCapped = "";
String stringRemaining = "";

//get the string from the end-user
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter any string: ");
String userInput = scan.nextLine();

//find the length of the string
int stringLength = userInput.length();

while (userInput.charAt(charSearch) != ' '){
//Here I need to replace each char with an uppercase until I reach a space
//then add the remaining string.
stringCapped = userInput.toUpperCase(charAt(charSearch))... + stringRemaining;

charSearch = ++charSearch;
}
```

Basically "Hello World" needs to become "HELLO World"

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
String orginal = "asdasd asda sdasdojk kjsdhfk hsdjfhdjs fhdsjf jhdf ";

System.out.println(orginal);
String firstWord = orginal.substring(0, orginal.indexOf(' '));
System.out.println(orginal.replace(firstWord, firstWord.toUpperCase()));
```

result:

```
asdasd asda sdasdojk kjsdhfk hsdjfhdjs fhdsjf jhdf 
ASDASD asda sdasdojk kjsdhfk hsdjfhdjs fhdsjf jhdf
```

Comment: Thanks MoshErsan! I think the teach wanted us to use a substring actually since the tast just prior to this one was to display any substring from the original string, makes perfect sense that the next part would be a more applied use of substring. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can try some thing like this

```
        // get the string from the end-user
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter any string: ");
    String userInput = scan.nextLine();

    // find the length of the string
    int stringLength = userInput.length();

    int firstWordEnd = userInput.indexOf(" ");

    String firstWord = userInput.substring(0, firstWordEnd);
    String newFirstWord = firstWord.toUpperCase();

    System.out.println(userInput.replace(firstWord, newFirstWord));
```

Comment: You can reduce the number of "String" created. Just to make sure it is understandable I have created a couple of Strings.

Comment: he is explaining, thats why he is using new String objects

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
int spaceIndex = userInput.indexOf(' ');
String upper = userInput.split(0, spaceIndex).toUpperCase() + userInput.split(spaceIndex);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let s be your string then string(s.charAt(0)).toUppercase().concat(s.substring(1)) should do. Not tried myself. You can look here (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

And the winner is:

```
  String userInput = "abc def abc nbc wral abc def nbc abc";
  String[] words = userInput.split(" ", 2); // split in 2 parts
  System.out.println(words[0].toUpperCase() + " " + words[1]);
```

Here is the output:

```
ABC def abc nbc wral abc def nbc abc
```